# Lista de visualización de canvas tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente problema, o más bien es una duda

Estoy haciendo una aplicación usando canvas con tkinter, dibujo varias figuras (puntos, líneas, rectángulos) el problema es que los debo dibujar en ese mismo orden y al dibujar los rectángulos quedan encima de los puntos y las lineas.

He leído en algunos sitios que canvas usa una lista y según la posición el objeto estará al fondo o en el frente, también dice q esa lista se puede re-ordenar pero no dicen como se hace.

¿Si es posible re-ordenar para tener los elementos en el orden que necesito? ¿O me estoy liando y existe otra forma más sencilla de hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar los métodos [`tag_lower` y `tag_raise`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_lower-method) del objeto canvas para reordenar los elementos que contiene.

Ejemplo de código:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

rect = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 200, 150, fill="yellow")
oval = canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 250, 200, fill="blue")

frame = tk.Frame()
tk.Button(frame, text="Lower rectangle", command=lambda: canvas.tag_lower(rect)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='WE')
tk.Button(frame, text="Raise rectangle", command=lambda: canvas.tag_raise(rect)).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='WE')
tk.Button(frame, text="Lower oval", command=lambda: canvas.tag_lower(oval)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='WE')
tk.Button(frame, text="Raise oval", command=lambda: canvas.tag_raise(oval)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='WE')
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo era justo lo que necesitaba hacer

Comment: @Guerra, puedes agradecerselo aceptando su respuesta si te ha solucionado el problema. Solo debes clicar en el tick verde debajo de la puntuación.  Con esto también ayudas a futuros usuarios a saber que esa es la respuesta que soluciona ese problema concreto.